# Setup.exe won't run

Tags: installation, installshield

I have a setup.exe install created via InstallShield project.
When I run this setup, it does not run. However I see it in the task manager.
Some times I resolve this problem when I restart my computer and try to install setup.. I have this problem in the some computer.

My program is 32 bit and my OS is Windows 7 - 64 bit.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Before you release your project by making setup project, you can change its mode to Any CPU mode. This mode's mean; Your project will run at x86/x64 bit operating sistems properly.

Here where you should check before you make the setup project.

[image: Here where you should check before you make setup project.]

if the problem continue, can you upload your simple project? So that I can help you more.

Comment: here I found a youtube link for your case; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mgu0y34HsVM